Updating the columns in two different tables
I have three tables.
The first table is CUSTOMER_MASTER_300724 and it has two columns INTEGRATION_ID and CUSTNO. One INTEGRATION_ID has only one CUSTNO. This is the backup table that contains 20K rows that have to be corrected in CUSTOMER table and CUSTOMER_ASSET table.
Second table is CUSTOMER which has the following columns: RID, INTEGRATION_ID, CUSTNO and other relevant columns. This is the master table for customers and has 500K rows. As per business logic, one INTEGRATION_ID has only one CUSTNO. However due to some job error one day, for one INTEGRATION_ID, two CUSTNO got created.
Third table is CUSTOMER_ASSET which has the following columns: RID, CONTACT_ID, RELATION_TYPE and other relevant columns. This consists of all the policies that the customer has. RELATION_TYPE has Owner, Life Assured, Beneficiary etc. This table has around 900K rows. As a result of the job error in the CUSTOMER table, this inter-table CUSTOMER_ASSET is also affected by creating unnecessary records for extra CUSTNO. I explained the situation visually below. CONTACT_ID is the foreign key in CUSTOMER_ASSET table and RID is the primary key in CUSTOMER table. Below is the join condition.
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMER CUS, CUSTOMER_ASSET CAST 
WHERE CUS.RID = CAST.CONTACT_ID;

Below are the tables structures.
CUSTOMER_MASTER_300724 backup table



INTEGRATION_ID
CUSTNO




BH432
97919693


HY902
87848986


WD3TH
76737471



CUSTOMER table



RID
INTEGRATION_ID
CUSTNO




53-ED
BH432
95929491


74-VB
BH432
97919693


1-2-ER
HY902
87848986


1-4-TS
HY902
87823564


85-UM
FOW35
345714472


39-AL
RT45EW
2346771


3-5-NM
WD3TH
74717572


5-9-VD
WD3TH
76737471



CUSTOMER_ASSET table



RID
CONTACT_ID
RELATION_TYPE




FT-453
53-ED
Owner


FT-454
53-ED
Life Assured


FT-459
74-VB
Owner


FT-460
74-VB
Payor


TT-461
74-VB
Beneficiary


TT-455
1-2-ER
Owner


TT-462
1-2-ER
Buyer


TT-456
1-4-TS
Owner


YT-457
1-4-TS
Payor


YT-458
85-UM
Owner


UT-470
85-UM
Beneficiary


IT-471
39-AL
Owner


OT-472
3-5-NM
Beneficiary


OT-473
3-5-NM
Owner


PT-474
5-9-VD
Payor



I wrote this procedure :
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPD_CON_DATA
AS
BEGIN

FOR REC IN
(
SELECT C.RID AS CORRECT_ID FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN CUSTOMER_MASTER_300724 BKP 
ON C.INTEGRATION_ID = BKP.INTEGRATION_ID
JOIN CUSTOMER_ASSET SAC ON C.RID = SAC.CONTACT_ID
WHERE C.CUSTNO = BKP.CUSTNO AND RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner'
)
LOOP
UPDATE CUSTOMER_ASSET
SET CONTACT_ID = REC.CORRECT_ID 
WHERE CONTACT_ID IN
(SELECT DISTINCT C.RID FROM CUSTOMER C JOIN CUSTOMER_MASTER_300724 BKP 
ON C.INTEGRATION_ID = BKP.INTEGRATION_ID WHERE C.CUSTNO != BKP.CUSTNO)
AND RELATION_TYPE = 'Owner';
END LOOP;

FOR REC IN
(
SELECT SAC.RID AS INCORRECT_ID FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN CUSTOMER_MASTER_300724 BKP 
ON C.INTEGRATION_ID = BKP.INTEGRATION_ID
JOIN CUSTOMER_ASSET SAC ON C.RID = SAC.CONTACT_ID
WHERE C.CUSTNO != BKP.CUSTNO AND RELATION_TYPE != 'Owner'
)
LOOP
UPDATE CUSTOMER_ASSET
SET CONTACT_ID = CONTACT_ID||'_BAD'
WHERE RELATION_TYPE != 'Owner'
AND RID = REC.INCORRECT_ID;
END LOOP;

FOR REC IN
(
SELECT C.RID FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_MASTER_300724 BKP 
ON C.INTEGRATION_ID = BKP.INTEGRATION_ID
WHERE C.CUSTNO != BKP.CUSTNO 
)
LOOP
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET INTEGRATION_ID = INTEGRATION_ID ||'_BAD'
WHERE RID = REC.RID;
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
RAISE;
END;

My final output in CUSTOMER table and CUSTOMER_ASSET table should be like this
CUSTOMER table



RID
INTEGRATION_ID
CUSTNO




53-ED
BH432_BAD
95929491


74-VB
BH432
97919693


1-2-ER
HY902_BAD
84818683


1-4-TS
HY902
87848986


85-UM
FOW35
345714472


39-AL
RT45EW
2346771


3-5-NM
WD3TH_BAD
74717572


5-9-VD
WD3TH
76737471



CUSTOMER_ASSET table



RID
CONTACT_ID
RELATION_TYPE




FT-453
74-VB
Owner


FT-454
53-ED_BAD
Life Assured


FT-459
74-VB
Owner


FT-460
74-VB
Payor


TT-461
74-VB
Beneficiary


TT-455
1-4-TS
Owner


TT-462
1-2-ER_BAD
Buyer


TT-456
1-4-TS
Owner


YT-457
1-4-TS
Payor


YT-458
85-UM
Owner


UT-470
85-UM
Beneficiary


IT-471
39-AL
Owner


OT-472
3-5-NM_BAD
Beneficiary


OT-473
5-9-VD
Owner


PT-474
5-9-VD
Payor



I executed the procedure shown, however the output was incorrect with as it is updating incorrectly in CUSTOMER and CUSTOMER_ASSET tables.
Could you assist in tweaking the procedure?
